# How to use PyCharm and WebStorm in the same editor

Tags: intellij-idea, reactjs, pycharm, webstorm

I'm working on a project involving python and javascript (react). I would like to know if someone knows a way to use pycharm and webstorm in the same editor or if there is a plugin to add react support to PyCharm.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All WebStorm features are available in PyCharm, though some of them are available as free plugins, e.g. Node.js.
For JSX support, switch the JavaScript version to JSX Harmony in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript.